# Where is the UI code in MVC pattern for application dev?

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

I've read up on MVC but am still unclear on whether there is a consensus whether the UI code (e.g., Qt) is part of the Viewer or the Controller. If I'm understanding some descriptions, the Viewer displays the model but the user interfaces directly with the controller, which I interpret as the UI is part of the controller. Other descriptions suggest the Viewer is for input and output, so contains all the UI code, freeing the controller to only handle the logic.

Are there two schools of thought on whether the UI code belongs in the Viewer or the Controller? If not, which one gets the UI code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different interpretations of MVC, but in general the view would be considered the correct place for UI code:

- The **View** is where the UI structure is defined.  I.e. where the button is, how the button looks etc.
- The **Controller** is where the logic relating to user interaction is defined. I.e. what happens to the model when the button is pressed, or what happens to the UI when the model changes.

Comment: It's worthy to note that the controller just relay some command/query to the model, it doesn't contain business logic

Answer (score 0):

MVC is always part of the UI in a classical 3-tier architecture. Sad but true :)  Also, the **Model** is quite vague since in an app we have plenty of contextual models: View Model, Business(Domain) Model, Persistence Model, Command/Query Model etc.

The original MVC was designed when the apps were much simpler. And of course, for trivial apps you don't need more than a MVC/MVVM Framework. For suchs apps you might not need to have such concrete and enforced boundaries, you can pile everything in controllers and use whatever single model for everything. A pragmatic solution *if* the app is simple enough.

But for non trivial apps, things are different and MVC is basically the UI architecture.

Comment: Care to comment downvoter? Or are you afraid you'll just show your ignorance? :)

Comment: This. MVC is a PRESENTATION pattern. There is a lot more of architecture decission beyond the controller.